# Binding values within a function to INSERT INTO DB

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, mysqli

Lets say I have this code:

```
$array = array('one' => $one, 'two' => $two);
$sql->sql_insert('table_name', $array);
```

I have the class object `$sql` and the function `sql_insert` but how would I use the mysqli prepared statements to bind the values and insert it into the db? And lets say the `mysqli connection` is `$this->connection`

Any advice would be great thanks.

edited:

```
function sql_insert_bind($table, $insert){

    $count = count($insert);
    $bind_val = '';
    for($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++){

        $bind_val .= '?, ';
    }

    $query = $this->connection->prepare('INSERT INTO `'.$table.'` VALUES ('.substr($bind_val, 0, -2).')');

    foreach($insert as $key => $value){

        $query->bind_param($key, $value);
    }

    $query->execute();
}
```

I get the error message: `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object` but `$this->connection` is the mysqli object

Comment: See edited code for my try. Thanks

Comment: I know you're already using MySQLi but PDO's API would be much easier to work with in this case

Comment: Whats better? PDO or Mysqli? I am rewriting my sql class at the moment so it doesn't really matter. Do you have a sample of PDO and this way? Thanks

Comment: Neither is *better*. It's really down to personal choice and how well each API fits in with what you're trying to accomplish. Since PDO supports named parameters, I figured it would work well in this case. See my answer for an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's how I would approach this with PDO (since OP asked)

I'll assume you've instantiated or injected a PDO object into your class as the `$connection` property, eg

```
class SQLClass {
    /**
     * @var PDO
     */
    private $connection;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo) {
        $this->connection = $pdo;
    }

    // etc
}

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password', array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

$sql = new SQLClass($pdo);
```

Then, in your `sql_insert_bind` method

```
$keys = array_keys($insert);

$cols = array_map(function($key) {
    return sprintf('`%s`', $key);
}, $keys);

$placeholders = array_map(function($key) {
    return sprintf(':%s', $key);
}, $keys);

$params = array_combine($placeholders, $insert);

$query = sprintf('INSERT INTO `%s` (%s) VALUES (%s)',
    $table, implode(',', $cols), implode(',', $placeholders));

$stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Comment: Would this use the bind function to securely secure the values? Such as not having to escaping the values manually?

Comment: @Jay Yes. `PDOStatement::execute` binds the parameters passed to it. See http://php.net/manual/pdostatement.execute.php#refsect1-pdostatement.execute-parameters

Comment: This works great. One thing tho. In my array some values can be either 'now()' OR 'NULL' OR '' (nothing). Because 'now()' is the time how would I resolve this? Thanks mate

Comment: @Jay You can't use parameters for static values like `NOW()` though you can use `null` (that's PHP `null`) and empty strings. You could just create a date/time string in PHP instead of using `NOW()`

Comment: Would there be away to get that function to replace `now()` into the current time? Also should I have backticks around the table names? Say I moved to a different db and not mysql, would the backticks cause an issue?

Comment: @Jay You could make some sort of `DBLiteral` class or something to hold the literal value and detect it whilst building your query (using `instanceof`). When found, you could inject the value directly rather than use binding. And yes, if you switched to another DB, you would need to replace the backticks with the appropriate identifier quote. Maybe take a look at the DB stuff in the Zend Framework. It does all these things quite well

Answer (score 1):

You should bind each variable seperately, [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) will accept many variables to bind:

```
$array = array('one' => $one, 'two' => $two);
$query = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (?, ?)");
$query->bind_param('ss', $array['one'], $array['two']);
$query->execute();
// inserted
```

Comment: This means the `sql_insert` method requires knowledge of the parameters coming in via the `$array` argument.