# Checkboxes and multiple input array to database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have read articles and questions regarding this issue but I'm still finding it difficult to go about it.

I'm trying to achieve course registration. So I have this table populated from my db.

```
<form method="post" action="courses.php">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Action<th>
      <th>Course Title<th>
      <th>Course  Code<th>
      <th>Course Unit<th>
    </thead>
 <tbody>
<!--Query that fetches the data from the db (included dbcon.php).. the courses are created by admin-->

<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="isChecked[]" value="<?php echo $course_id?>"></td>

<td><input type="hidden" name="ctitle[]" value="<?php echo $title?>"> <?php echo $title?></td>

<td><input type="hidden" name="ccode[]" value="<?php echo $code?>"> <?php echo $code?></td>

<td><input type="hidden" name="cunit[]" value="<?php echo $unit?>"> <?php echo $unit?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="enroll"> 
</form>
```

*If a checkbox is checked, How can I get all the values of the array **(title, code, unit)** and insert them on its corresponding column in my enroll table also note that the courses are more than 1?*
here is the little I have done but I'm beginning to think that I'm not going to go through with it (imaging creating another foreach of the array? initializing a counter foreach??)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['enroll'])){
    $i=0;
    if(!empty ($_POST['isChecked'])){
        foreach($_POST['isChecked'] as $course){  
        $course = $_POST['isChecked'][$i];
        $query = "INSERT INTO enrolled (course_id) 
        VALUES ('$course')";
        $insert = $db->query($query);
        $i++;
    }
}?>
```

The above insert the course id to my DB quite fine. But what I want is to actually insert all the data i.e (id, title, code, and unit to the database )

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your code is wrong. Try this:

```
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="isChecked['course_id']" value="<?php echo $course_id?>"></td>

<td><input type="hidden" name="isChecked['title']" value="<?php echo $title?>"> <?php echo $title?></td>

<td><input type="hidden" name="isChecked['code']" value="<?php echo $code?>"> <?php echo $code?></td>

<td><input type="hidden" name="isChecked['unit']" value="<?php echo $unit?>"> <?php echo $unit?></td>
</tr>
```

Do not forget to BIND your values and check them before to execute your SQL code.

Comment: please can this go through if the values are going to multiple columns and not just one column in my database??..

Comment: @Onuche Abraham DaCatalyst explaine

Comment: @Onuche Abraham DaCatalyst It all depends how you create your `insert` statement and what `db` fields configuration do you have.

Comment: can you clarify on the binding aspect? i think the first comment wasn't the right question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393438/binding-values-within-a-function-to-insert-into-db

Comment: I'm using mysqli.. i haven't really done it with PDO as stated in the answer to that question... i have a simple connection....  `$db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);` sorry if this is not what you mean.. i just need more clarity..

Comment: At the end guy explained `$query = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO 'table' VALUES (?, ?)");
$query->bind_param('ss', $array['one'], $array['two']);` take a look. and search for `how to properly insert parameters in query for mysqli`

Comment: in a moment... I'm giving it a trial

Comment: a last one please... since i now have `isChecked['title']`, can i ` $title = $_POST['isChecked']['title'];` ?  or how??

Comment: @OnucheAbrahamDaCatalyst Yes you can ever way, since you know the order of items submitted

Comment: I can't reach you via dm. this seem to be a long comment... I'm getting a notice error: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\course\student\process\enrol.php on line 24

Comment: @OnucheAbrahamDaCatalyst it means something you doing wrong with your php code

Comment: @OnucheAbrahamDaCatalyst It is easy to open a new question on `How to insert post data to DB` it will help to post your code in proper way and get the good answer. It is hard to tell the weakness of your code but it defensively has some errors .